# What's the meaning of VJ in Korean TV show Running Man?

Tags: running-man

I am watching [Running Man](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Running_Man_%28TV_series%29) recently. I noticed that they often use the word `VJ` to refer to the person who hold the camera. However I don't know the full name of this abbreviation. I can guess that V may stand for Video. But I don't know what J stand for? Please help, thanks.

Comment: Hint:[https://www.google.com/search?num=100&q=acronym:+VJ&spell=1](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&q=acronym:+VJ&spell=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VJ, back in the days when MTV played videos, was short for "Video Jockey".  It was meant to rhyme with DJ or "Disc Jockey", since they were both playing music.

I've also heard VJ used for "Video Journalist".  So, based on what I know about that show, it's probably somewhere between the two.

EDIT: Based on [this article](http://www.allkpop.com/article/2011/09/behind-the-scenes-with-running-man-cameraman-ryu-kwon-ryeol), it looks like Video Journalist is the correct answer.